# rWishart: should be $dof>p-1$ or $dof \ge p$?

Tags: r, wishart-distribution

The degrees of freedom $n$ of a Wishart distribution parametrized like in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution) (and like most people do) are restricted to:
$$
n>p-1
$$

where $p$ are the dimensions of the data, to ensure that the Gamma function in the normalization factor is applied to a positive number.

However, as for `R` implementations, both `rWishart`(stats) and`rwish`(MCMCpack) functions want me to choose $n\ge p$ (as if $n$ was an integer number). Otherwise it complains:

```
> S <- toeplitz((2:1)/10)
> rWishart(1, 1.5, S)
Error in rWishart(1, 1.5, S) : 
  inconsistent degrees of freedom and dimension
```

Note that my $n$ are real numbers, not integers, since I am generating the degrees of freedom $n$ from a Gamma distribution according to:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n-p+1} \sim \mathcal{G}(1, 1/p)
\end{align}

Shouldn't the `R` implementations accept  $n>p-1$? I could copy the source code and hack it to do so, but this seems very strange to me. It is like the libraries do one thing while the books do the other (all of them with the same parametrization)

Who is right? (or what am I missing here?)

Comment: Looking at the Bartlett decomposition, it seems that $n\ge p-1$ is all that is required, and the R packages are mildly deficient in this regard.

Comment: @shabbychef I think you mean $n > p - 1$, because if $n = p - 1$ then the last component on the diagonal will be $\chi^2$ with $0$ degrees of freedom. OP, for reference, see [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution#Bartlett_decomposition).

Comment: @guy A $\chi^2$ with 0 d.f. is identically zero!

Comment: ```> rchisq(10,df=0)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: It seems the R implementation is not right or that it only considers integer numbers of freedoms. It also seems that the python implementation in scipy will have the same issue. Can you do the honors and write a short answer so that we can close it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `matrixsampling` package.

```
library(matrixsampling)
Sigma <- toeplitz(2:1)/10
rwishart(2, nu = 1.5, Sigma)
```

It also allow `nu <= p-1` at condition that `nu` is an integer (in this case the Wishart distribution generates semi-definite matrices).